# Puny HFS performance

Tags: macos, hfs

Is it normal to have less than 15 megabytes per second writes on a
solid state drive (Evo 850 250GB to be exact)?

```
$ date;dd if=/dev/random of=/var/tmp/test bs=4096 count=81920;date
Tue Nov 22 16:59:00 +03 2016
81920+0 records in
81920+0 records out
335544320 bytes transferred in 23.296377 secs (14403283 bytes/sec)
Tue Nov 22 16:59:24 +03 2016
```

This is the order of magnitude less than than the theoretical ceiling
of 150 MB/s for SATA 1.0 that Apple chose to keep forcing down the
Mac mini user throats. And no, this is not a Mac mini but the very latest iMac 5K.

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, /dev/random turned out to be expensive:

```
$ date;dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/tmp/test bs=4096 count=81920;date
Tue Nov 22 17:05:55 +03 2016
81920+0 records in
81920+0 records out
335544320 bytes transferred in 0.719295 secs (466490534 bytes/sec)
Tue Nov 22 17:05:56 +03 2016
```

Comment: Neither question nor answer show much research how proper (SSD|HDD) benchmarking works (sequential r/w, 4k r/w etc)

Comment: Right, I needed a rough estimate. And I think I got the jist of it.